# How to instantiate my C++ class from QtScript? My class inherits QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

I am researching possibilities of QtScript. I understand that it is possible to create `QObject` in C++ and then pass it into `QScriptEngine`:

```
QObject *someObject = new WindowWithText;
QScriptValue objectValue = engine.newQObject(someObject);
engine.globalObject().setProperty("window", objectValue);
```

This works - I was able to call my methods defined in C++:

[image: image description]

`WindowWithText` declaration:

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class WindowWithText;
}

class WindowWithText : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit WindowWithText(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~WindowWithText();
public slots:
  void setHeading(const QString&);
  void setContents(const QString&);
  QString getHeading() const;

private:
  Ui::WindowWithText *ui;
};
```

But I would like to instantiate windows from qtscript itself, like this:

```
var window = new WindowWithText();
```

I understand **I will probably have to write some proxy between constructor and QtCcript, but how to do it?**

So far, I just created **`static`** method `newInstance` that creates the object, but that's no `new`:

```
QScriptValue WindowWithText::newInstance(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
  QObject *someObject = new WindowWithText;
  QScriptValue objectValue = engine->newQObject(someObject);
  return objectValue;
}
```

I exported it to the engine as follows:

```
engine.globalObject().setProperty("WindowWithText", engine.newFunction(WindowWithText::newInstance));
```

This does not use `new` though and isn't true javascript pseudoclass:

[image: image description]

Following code will fail:

```
function Subclass() {
  this.setHeading("bla bla");
}
Subclass.prototype = Object.create(WindowWithText.prototype);

var window = new dd();
window.show();
```

Error caused by the fact that `WindowWithText.prototype` doesn't have anything to do with `WindowWithText`:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'this.setHeading' [undefined] is not a function.
```

Is there more reliable and **less tedious** way of exporting C++ classes to my engine?